# How to change the value of a JLabel in runtime?

Tags: java, swing

I want to change the image a JLabel is viewing during runtime, but I keep getting NullPointerExceptions or nothing happens when I press the magic button that's supposed to do things. Is it even possible in Java?

Here is my code in its entirety:

```
    import java.text.*;
    import javax.swing.text.*;
    import java.util.*;
    import java.awt.*;
    import java.awt.event.*;
    import javax.swing.*;
    import javax.swing.event.*;

    public class Shell implements ActionListener, MenuKeyListener
    {
        JFrame frame;
        JWindow window;
        JButton PSubmit;
        JPanel pane1, pane2;
        JRadioButton R1, R2, R3;
            ButtonGroup PGroup;
        JTabbedPane layout;

        String result;
        String border = "Border.png";
        String DF = "Frame.png";
        String list [];
        Driver driver;

        public Shell()
        {
            driver = new Driver();
            list = new String [6];
        }

        public void setFrame()
        {
            frame = new JFrame("Pokemon Program 3 by Systems Ready");
            frame.setSize(600, 600);
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            frame.setVisible(true);
            frame.getContentPane().setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        }
        public void frameLayout()
        {
            layout = new JTabbedPane();
            JPanel pane1 = new JPanel();
            JPanel pane2 = new JPanel();
            JLabel label = new JLabel("Please choose the restrictions:");
            JLabel imgLabel1 = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(border));
            JLabel notiLabel1 = new JLabel("The Pokemon chosen with these restrictions are:       ");
            JLabel notiLabel2 = new JLabel("'No Restrictions': No restrictions for the kind of Pokemon chosen based on species or items.");
            JLabel notiLabel3 = new JLabel("'Battle Revolution': All Pokemon must have unique items.");
            JLabel notiLabel4 = new JLabel("'Battle Tower': All Pokemon must have unique items, Uber and Event Legendaries banned.");
            JLabel label2 = new JLabel("Please choose possible Pokemon:");
            pane1.add(label);
            pearlButtons();
            pane1.add(R1);
            pane1.add(R2);
            pane1.add(R3);
            pane1.add(PSubmit);
            pane1.add(notiLabel2);
            pane1.add(notiLabel3);
            pane1.add(notiLabel4);
            pane1.add(imgLabel1);
            pane1.add(notiLabel1);
            JLabel pokeLabel1 = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(DF));
            JLabel pokeLabel2 = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(DF));
            JLabel pokeLabel3 = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(DF));
            JLabel pokeLabel4 = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(DF));
            JLabel pokeLabel5 = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(DF));
            JLabel pokeLabel6 = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(DF));
            pane1.add(pokeLabel1);
            pane1.add(pokeLabel2);
            pane1.add(pokeLabel3);
            pane1.add(pokeLabel4);
            pane1.add(pokeLabel5);
            pane1.add(pokeLabel6);
            pane2.add(label2);
            layout.add("Pearl Version", pane1);
            layout.add("SoulSilver Version", pane2);
            frame.add(layout);
        }
        public void pearlButtons()
        {
            PGroup = new ButtonGroup();
            R1 = new JRadioButton("No Restrictions", true);
            R1.setActionCommand("N");
            R1.setVisible(true);
            R2 = new JRadioButton("Battle Revolution");
            R2.setActionCommand("BR");
            R2.setVisible(true);
            R3 = new JRadioButton("Battle Tower");
            R3.setActionCommand("B");
            R3.setVisible(true);
            PGroup.add(R1);
            PGroup.add(R2);
            PGroup.add(R3);
            PSubmit = new JButton("Submit");
            PSubmit.setActionCommand("pstart");
            PSubmit.setVisible(true);
            PSubmit.addActionListener(this);
        }
        public void pearlProcessing()
        {
                    //The "list" array has a bunch of string names that get .png affixed to them (and I named the image files as such when I name them)
            String file1 = list[0] + ".png";
            String file2 = list[1] + ".png";
            String file3 = list[2] + ".png";
            String file4 = list[3] + ".png";
            String file5 = list[4] + ".png";
            String file6 = list[5] + ".png";
    /*-------------------------------------------------------------------------------//
                    This is where the method's supposed to go to change the image...
                    I've tried pokeLabel = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(file1));, but that yields a NullPointerException.
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
        }
        public static void main(String[] args)
        {
            Shell test = new Shell();
            test.setFrame();
            test.frameLayout();
            test.frame.setVisible(true); 
        }
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
            if ("pstart".equals(e.getActionCommand()))
            {
                result = PGroup.getSelection().getActionCommand();
                if (result.equals("N"))
                {
                    list = driver.Prandom();
                    pearlProcessing();
                }
                else
                    System.out.println("Not done yet! ;)");
            }
        } 

        public void menuKeyPressed(MenuKeyEvent e)  
        {
            System.out.println("pressed");
        }
        public void menuKeyReleased(MenuKeyEvent e)
        {
            System.out.println("menuKeyReleased");
        }
        public void menuKeyTyped(MenuKeyEvent e)
        {
            System.out.println("menuKeyTyped");
        }

    }
```

Comment: I don't think the line you've indicated can cause a `NullPointerException`. Can you post the actual stack trace?

Comment: Have you run this through a debugger ? What is the file name, and does it exist right before you try to create the new JLabel ?

Comment: @Micheal Mrozek: Yeah, you're right. I was in a hurry when I wrote this. xD;; When I moved the line "pane1.add(pokeLabel1);" to where I indicated in the comment lines, I got a NullPointerException (instead of something more reasonable, like an exception saying "NO YOU CAN'T ADD STUFF DURING RUNTIME"); the exception cites that line and the line that calls the function it's in, and then the rest cited is the package source code. The code I mentioned in the comment box doesn't cause anything to happen by itself for some reason, which is so frustrating when I want the image to change!

Comment: @Romain Hippeau: I...don't know how to run it through a debugger, ahaha. I'm kind of a newbie at this. 

The filename is along the lines of [Pokemon name].png. The function in another .java (code not listed here) returns a string array of random names, which I concatenated with .png (with the variables file1, file2, etc.). Upon using a debug statement to print them out, the names turned out like they were supposed to, and I made sure to name the image files as such so that it would work.

Out of curiosity on that note, wouldn't that yield a FileNotFound Exception if the filename was wrong?

Comment: before this ...
 I've tried pokeLabel = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(file1));, but that yields a NullPointerException.  

Can you try System.out.println(file1) and report what it says ?

Comment: @user A `NullPointerException` has nothing to do with adding stuff at runtime; it means you tried to use a null variable where it's not allowed. Is either `pane1` or `pokeLabel1` null at that spot?

Comment: @Romain He initializes it right before that spot, so if it's null he's leaving out code somewhere

Comment: @Romain: Nightmare.png was printed. Which is a good thing.
@Micheal: Pane1 and pokeLabel1 shouldn't be null. Both Pane1 and pokeLabel1 appear like they're supposed to upon running the class file - Pane1 containing the content and pokeLabel1 only showing an outline (which is what "Frame.png" is) like they're supposed to. Any problems that occur in the program occur when the pearlProcessing function is called after pressing Submit with "No Restrictions" chosen. This is my first time trying to work a GUI, so I'm not sure if changing an image for a label already doing something is possible. xD;;

Comment: @Micheal: Pane1 and pokeLabel1 shouldn't be null. Both Pane1 and pokeLabel1 appear like they're supposed to upon running the class file - Pane1 containing the content and pokeLabel1 only showing an outline (which is what "Frame.png" is) like they're supposed to. Any problems that occur in the program occur when the pearlProcessing function is called after pressing Submit with "No Restrictions" chosen. This is my first time trying to work a GUI, so I'm not sure if changing an image for a label already doing something is possible. xD;;

Answer (score 2):

Without knowing if this is the cause, I would change

```
 result = PGroup.getSelection().getActionCommand();
 if (result.equals("N")) {
```

to

```
 ButtonModel selection = PGroup.getSelection();
 result = (selection==null ? null : selection.getActionCommand()); 
 if ("N".equals(result)) {
 // etc...
```

This guards against likely null pointers.

Answer (score 0):

I highly suggest whenever you get any exception to *always* look at the stack trace and see where the actual line the exception occurred at was.

But if I were to speculate, you call `PGroup.getSelection()` in your `actionPerformed` method. This method *may* return `null` if there is no button selected in your radio button group. I also noticed that you do not set an initially selected radio button (call `setSelected(true)` on the radio button). Thus, if the selected radio button is `null` calling `getActionCommand` will result in a `NullPointerException`.